# in laravel controller how to pass variable from one function to other function

Tags: php, laravel-4

this is my laravel's controller function.

```
    public function getDefault()
    {
return View::make('layouts.default');
}

    public function getURL()
{
    $name = Input::all();
    $url=$name['url'];
    $json_data=file_get_contents($url);
    $content=json_decode($json_data,true);
    $this->getThemeOne( $content );
    return View::make('hello');

}
```

how to pass data of $content to all function:

```
   public function getThemeOne($content)
{
  return View::make('themes.home')->with('data',$content);
}


public function getAbout($content)
{
  return View::make('themes.about')->with('content',$content);
}
```

route code:

```
     Route::get('/','DataController@getDefault');//home page
     Route::get('/view','DataController@getThemeOne');
     Route::post('/', 'dataController@getURL'); //post url from home page
```

view pages:

```
hello.blade.php:
{ link to goto home.blade.php}->
<a href="view">home</a>

home.blade.php:
{{$data['about']}}
```

please help me how to do this...

Comment: Where does `getURL()` is being called?

Comment: Is the problem solved or not? If you still get the parameter error, make sure your `json_decode()` return is valid.

Comment: return from json_decode() is valid...i want to tell you that i have 20 functions in controller which requires $content data...is there anyway   to this through a function..

Comment: Ok now I understand, I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

To share data accross views you can use in your function `getURL()`:

```
View::share('content', $content);
```

---

You can pass `$content` as a parameter to your function and to your view like this:

```
public function x {
   $name = Input::all();
   $url=$name['url'];
   $json_data=file_get_contents($url);
   $content=json_decode($json_data,true);

   $this->getThemeOne( $content ); // or whatever your scope is
 }



public function getThemeOne( $content )
{
    return View::make('themes.home')->with('content', $content);
}
```

See the docs http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working...error is Missing argument 1 for DataController::getThemeOne().

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code? Did you pass an argument? The error says you did not pass an argument...

Comment: m new in laravel...please tell me how to access the shared variable on view pages

Comment: On the view page you can access it via `$content`. Read the docs on the link I posted.

Comment: i only get data on view page returned in getURL() function.and in other view pages returned through different functions its showing error Undefined variable: content

Comment: You must call `View::share('content', $content);` of course anywhere you get input you want to share.

Comment: Another solution is to define a `before` filter that shares the input data